Multivector hybridsearch function is not working
I followed the documentation:https://milvus.io/docs/multi-vector-search.md to perform a multivector hybrid search, but I encountered an error when performing Step 3: Perform a Hybrid Search.
res = collection.hybrid_search(
    reqs, # List of AnnSearchRequests created in step 1
    rerank, # Reranking strategy specified in step 2
    limit=2 # Number of final search results to return
)

print(res)
----------------------------------------
grpc RpcError: [hybrid_search], <_InactiveRpcError: StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED, unknown method HybridSearch for service milvus.proto.milvus.MilvusService>, <Time:{'RPC start': '2024-06-20 04:18:00.304044', 'gRPC error': '2024-06-20 04:18:00.352937'}>

It suggests that the HybridSearch method is not implemented or recognized by the Milvus service. I checked my version of both Milvus and the Python client, and they are both 2.4.x, which should include this hybrid_search method.
Is there any workaround for this issue?
